# Round label value in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, label, rounding

Hi I have the code for a mileage calculator but the displayed mileage is a really long number. What adaptations should I make to the code to get the displayed mileage to round to one decimal place?

Thanks.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var directionDisplay;
    var map;


function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var copenhagen = new google.maps.LatLng(55.6771, 12.5704);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom:12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: copenhagen
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    }


    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    var distanceInput = document.getElementById("distance");

        var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1609.3440006146921597227828997904;
        }
    });
    }
    </script>

    <title>Distance Calculator</title>

    <style type="text/css">

            body {
                font-family:Helvetica, Arial;
            }
            #map_canvas {
                height: 50%;
            }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <body onload="initialize()">
    <p>Enter your current location and desired destination to get the distance</p>
        <div>
            <p>
                <label for="start">Start: </label>
                <input type="text" name="start" id="start" />

                <label for="end">End: </label>
                <input type="text" name="end" id="end" />

                <input type="submit" value="Calculate Route" onclick="calcRoute()" />
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="distance">Distance (km): </label>
                <input type="text" name="distance" id="distance" readonly="true" />
            </p>
    </div>
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>

javascript google geolocation maps
```

Comment: Check out `toFixed` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: have you checked round() in javascript http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_round.asp

Comment: or parseInt(), even substr

Comment: Yes but I don't know where to place them. I have tried doing Maths.round(distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1609.3440006146921597227828997904); but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can someone please help!!!